# ViewExpiredException

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2, myfaces

I am using JSF 2 ,primefaces 2.2.RC2 ,google-appengine
I recently moved from myfaces-2.0.0.beta3 to myfaces-bundle-2.0.3.
With this new version, I am getting the below exception very frequently,much before the actual session timeout.

```
/login.jsfNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /login.jsf

Caused by:
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException - /login.jsfNo saved view state could be   found for the view identifier: /login.jsf
```

I have set my session timeout to 10 mins.

By seeing other blog I have set true for facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE parameter.
But that doesn't help

---

I couldn't make mojarra-2.0.4-FCS to work with GAE.
After modifying WebConfiguration.java ,mojarra-2.0.3-FCS is working with GAE.
But I get new exception frequently

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at   
java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571) at   
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349) at   javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:161) at
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1428) –
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myfaces-2.0.2,myfaces-2.0.1 is having the same issue.
myfaces-2.0.0 works.

Answer (score 0):

> I recently moved from myfaces-2.0.0.beta3 to myfaces-bundle-2.0.3.

If that's the only change, then it's just a bug in MyFaces 2.0.3. [Report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/BrowseProjects.jspa) it to them. In the meanwhile, you can try using [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) rather than MyFaces.