# ajax and viewscoped don't work on google app engine wit jsf2 and primefaces

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean, view-scope

I want to create one application with jsf2.1 and primefaces and google app engine

but when I tested this  :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>GAE + JSF</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Google App Engine + JSF 2.0 example - hello.xhtml</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
        <p:commandButton value="Welcome Me" actionListener="#{helloBean.tester}" update="dlg"
        oncomplete="dlgw.show();" >
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{helloBean.name}" target="#{helloBean.nameDialog}" />      
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:dialog id="dlg" widgetvar="dlgw" >
                je suis #{helloBean.nameDialog}
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

the methode "tester" is not invoked when I click on the commandButton and the dialog is not launched

I don't know the cause

here is the managed bean  :

```
    package com.esperant;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private String nameDialog;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void tester(){
        System.out.println("tester methode");
    }

    public String getNameDialog() {
        return nameDialog;
    }

    public void setNameDialog(String nameDialog) {
        this.nameDialog = nameDialog;
    }

}
```

do you have any idea about the problem

thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7172335/617373

Comment: I have already seen the post before but I did not understand it , can you explain me more ;)

Comment: for start , try to work it out with sessionScoped... if it works for you and only with viewscope it does not let me know...

Comment: with sessionScoped the actionListener method is invoked only once (the first ) and the dialog is not launched

Comment: does the dialog opens if your remove the ` <f:setPropertyActionListener` ?

Comment: [Attribute names are case sensitive](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/dialog.html)